# Error while taking backup in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, backup

I was trying to take a backup of an existing VM. But unfortunately it failed while configuring backup itself. Indeed it was actually provisioned from an backup of an existing machine which was already backed up. How come now alone I could not take a backup? The error was

> Error Code: UserErrorGuestAgentStatusUnavailable
>
> Error Message: VM agent is unable to communicate with the Azure Backup
>   Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overcame with the issue by taking an **image** with the help of Backup failed machine's root **disk VHD URI** and tried launching the machine with that image and was able to take backup with no data loss.

Answer (score 0):

> Error Code: UserErrorGuestAgentStatusUnavailable
>   Error Message: VM
>   agent is unable to communicate with the Azure Backup Service.

According to your error message, we should check your VM agent status.

We can **add a blank disk in the VM to refresh the agent state**, then try again.

We should make sure the agent are the **latest version**, please refer to this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-troubleshoot-vm-backup-fails-snapshot-timeout#causes-and-solutions).

Also here a similar [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e41f2545-34eb-4d18-88b2-4bf888dbe902/azure-recovery-services-vault-deployment-fails-with-usererrorguestagentstatusunavailable?forum=windowsazureonlinebackup) about you, please refer to it.

Comment: But the agent was running only and  i updated to the latest version also. Adding blank disk also failed to take backup. I was referring official document for the past two days but still i could not come up with a solution.

Comment: @PrasithPrabhu classic VM or Azure ARM VM?

Comment: @PrasithPrabhu please check $vm.VM.ProvisionGuestAgent, use Powershell to get $vm info, and find the ProvisionGuestAgent.

Comment: FYI, I'm using an Ubuntu Vm. I can't use powershell.